# How to make my interstitial ad pop up after x amount of clicks?

Tags: swift, xcode, admob

I have this code that worked in Objective-C but doesn't work when I converted it to Swift. What I'm trying to do is get an ad to pop up after every 15th click.

```css
import UIKit
import Firebase
import AVFoundation

class Page1: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {
    
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
    
    var counter: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "6splash.png")!)

    
    }


    @IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {
        if counter % 15 == 0 {
            if interstitial?.isReady != nil {
                interstitial?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
            }
            else {
                
            }
        }
        counter += 1
    }
    
    func createAndLoadInterstitial() {
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712")
        interstitial?.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial?.load(request)
    }
    
    func interstitial(_ interstitial: GADInterstitial, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("interstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ interstitial: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
        createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }

}
```

I followed Google's tutorial on getting an interstitial to show and that works, but that is for making it pop up every time. When I try my implementation it's not showing ads at all. What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when you step through the code? When you put a breakpoint in `playAgain()`, can you see if it's hitting any of the code?

My first assumption is that your `IBAction` is not wired up correctly in your storyboard.

Comment: I went to double-check my storyboard and I do have it wired up. I made sure to unlink it and relink it again to no avail. I'll go check the tutorial again and see if I missed anything and the code is incomplete. All I know is Xcode isn't throwing an error.

Comment: And you're sure the IBAction is actually wired up within the storyboard? I can take screenshots right now, but you need to make sure that when you see that action, it is selected as the "Touch Up Inside" action for the button.

Comment: I was actually able to find an image from another question of mine. This is what the Connection Inspector should look like, and this is the event wired up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTJ8o.png

Comment: Thanks for the image, it helps narrow down the problem. Looks like my connection inspector is the same, I think my implementation just isn't right. I think I should put the ad code after super.viewdidload and then call an ad with my IBAction.

Comment: From your comments it sounds like your current code sample doesn’t reflect what you have at this time. Can you update it?

Comment: I’m also only on mobile so I can’t dive too deep, but there are some quirks. The isReady != nil line should probably instead be isReady == true, for example.

Comment: I reverted it back to the original code. My original idea didn't work out like I expected. I changed from nil to true however. There are probably more quirks in the code to be found, I used an Objective-C converter to give me what I currently have.

Comment: So it turns out I missed some setup instructions in the AppDelegate ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  also my converted code was close but not exactly the same in the google example. I'll update soon on my progress.

Comment: Still haven't found a solution after updating the AppDelegate. It shows an ad the first click but doesn't follow the logic and then show an ad on the 15th click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! It wasn't var counter that was causing the problem like I thought it was, rather it was the AdMob code. My AdMob was caching an ad and showing them once and then not caching/creating new ads, so regardless of the counter or not it will only display one ad. I followed a video tutorial (Geeky Lemon) that showed me how to properly cache and load ads. I then reenabled my var counter code and everything worked like it was supposed to. It shows an ad every 15th click. Here is the code.

```css
class Page1: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {
    
    
    
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
    
    var counter: Int = 0
    

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    
       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "6splash.png")!)
        
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.load(request)
        

    }

 
  
    @IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {
        if counter % 15 == 0 {
            if interstitial.isReady {
                interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
                interstitial = CreateAd()
            } else {
                print("Ad wasn't ready")
            }
        }
        counter += 1
    }

    

   }

func CreateAd() -> GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}
```

Literally struggled for days. Turns out I was looking at the wrong place the whole time. I thought for sure it had to be the var counter because I converted those snippets from objective-c and followed Google's very own Swift tutorial for how to integrate their sdk. I was just loading a single ad and that's why I thought the counter was broken.

Answer (score 0):

```css
class Page1: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {
    
    
    
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
    
    var counter: Int = 0
    

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    
       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "6splash.png")!)
        
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.load(request)
        

    }

 
  
    @IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {
        if counter % 15 == 0 {
            if interstitial.isReady {
                interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
                interstitial = CreateAd()
            } else {
                print("Ad wasn't ready")
            }
        }
        counter += 1
    }

    

   }

func CreateAd() -> GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).